# Properties of set $\{X∈ M_n(\mathbb{C}) | \operatorname{adj}(X)=I_n\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

"For $n≥4$, let $U=\{X∈ M_n(\mathbb{C}) |  \operatorname{adj}X=I\}$. Which of the following statements are true/false? Justify:

1. $U$ contains $n-1$ elements,
2. $U$ contains only scalar matrices,
3. if $X_1,\, X_2∈U$, then $X_1X_2∈U$
4. if $X_1, X_2∈ U$, then $X_1+X_2∈ U$"

I honestly don't know how to begin. I suppose for the last 2 statements if you know that $U$ is a subspace, you could solve it straightforwardly, but I don't even know how to get to that point.

Do I need to use the fact that |A| A<sup>-1</sup> = adjA?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 4):

Clearly, such a amtrix must be invertible, so that $\det X \neq 0$. Start from the property of $\mathrm{adj} X $
$$X \cdot \mathrm{adj} X = (\det X) \cdot  I$$
Since $\mathrm{adj} X=1$, you have
$$X= (\det X) I$$
thus, $X$ is a scalar matrix. Taking determinant, you have
$$\det X = (\det X)^n$$
thus $\det X = e^{\frac{2 k \pi i}{n-1}}$ must be equal to a root of unity for some $k \in \{ 1, \dots , n-1\}$.

After this, check that this condition is also sufficient. Thus 1,2,3 are true; 4 is false.

Comment: How did you arrive at detX=e^2kπ/n−1 ?

Comment: Because $\det X$ satisfies the equation $x^n=x$, or, equivalently, $x^{n-1}=1$.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand it now except for one little detail: Why doesn't the possible values of k start from 0, in which case there would be n elements in U ({0,1,2,...n-1})? Isn't e^0 also a solution?

Comment: Because for $k=n-1$ and for $k=0$ you have $$e^{0}=1=e^{2 \pi i}$$ they are the same

Comment: Of course. Thank you so much!